# Why VOl & IOL are seperately specified in I2C?

Tags: i2c

When the specification Mentions VOL for a conditioned IOL then why they define IOL again?[image]

Comment: Note how they appear under different columns: Parameter and Condition.

Comment: You asked the same question a few days ago. The answer hasn’t changed since then.

Comment: OP has asked this before and is still asking? Okay. Ask yourself this: You have a slowest and fastest running speed. If I ask you how fast you can make a delivery, are you going to say one of those speeds? Or are you going to ask me how heavy the package is so you can figure out your actual speed?

Comment: DKNguyen, I still didn't get it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are VOL and IOL seperately defined in I2C and SMBUS?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519207/why-are-vol-and-iol-seperately-defined-in-i2c-and-smbus)

Comment: One is the max/min limits, the other is a condition another measurement is being taken at. I don't know how it can be any more clear. You need to think about the test circuit being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different I2C modes and have different specifications due to speed requirements, and the specs also differ based on supply voltage as at low voltages the current sinking ability is less too. That's all there is to it.

Faster speeds require higher currents (stronger pull-ups to be faster) and have relaxed Vol specs.